# Define a char array with a size which does not count the null character

Tags: c, string, memory, char

I am asked to say whether the following piece of code triggers any error or warning:

```
char string[5] = "hello";
```

I have tested it on my computer and it worked fine (no error/warning and `printf` gave the expected value ("hello") and `strlen` gave the expected value (5)). However, I would be tempted to say that this yields some kind of undefined behaviour. I suppose this is considered a bad practice anyway, but can it cause an error since we are not explicitly allowing a byte for the null character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's allowed. Source: K&R C, ANSI C version. "A char array may be initialized with a string of that many characters." This results in a string that is not null terminated--use with caution. This means that `printf("%s", string);` isn't defined but `printf("%.5s", string);` is.

Appearing to work is a possible result of undefined behavior. In fact on examples like this, the last thing in the file's `.data` region will be the string, which then gets padded with zeros to match the machine alignment. On the stack, when the program first starts up, uninitialized memory in `main` tends to have the same condition of being zeroed (this was not always the case, and in no case should any code *ever* depend on this). Thus resulting in everything appearing to work. But when the program gets bigger, it stops working for no apparent reason because memory layout or initialization changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, printf("%s", string) did work on my computer and show "hello", and `strlen` returned 5. How can we explain this?

Comment: @user8171079: Added stuff on the appearing to work

Comment: @MartinJames: Not luck. Toy examples of this tend to work because of security reasons.

Comment: @Joshua: So your implementation has added 0 bytes after the string for whatever reason. Others (or compiled with other options) might (and will) not, e.g. for 8-Bit MCUs. I nevertheless call this "luck". How would you? Also That  book is pretty outdated and contains quite some bugs. As usual, the correct way is to reference a first level source unless unavailable. Here it available with ISO9899.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: K&R is first level source and if it conflicted with the ISO source from the same time I would believe K&R over the ISO source. It is dated now, but they rarely change things so that valid code becomes invalid.

Comment: @Joshua: It is not. The only first leven source back then was the standard and K&R just explained and interpreted it. Among the usual bugs every book has is that ANSI is not C anymore since now over 21 years already. Just to spare me the expectable follow-up: That does not imply the standard has changed in this particular aspect.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: Considering that K&R was written by some of the compiler authors ...

Comment: @Joshua: Long time ago. Times are a-changin' ! Note that there has not even been an update for C99. And that did change quite some smantics and behaviour of the language (unfortunately not that one).

Comment: Btw: I checked if gcc provides an option to warn, but couldn't find one. That's one reason wen should not use a fixed length array with string initialisers. But that's not possible for all usecases (e.g. a `struct` member). One way to avoid that would be wrapping the literal in a macro, but that requires discipline by all programmers.

Answer (score 0):

In C the compiler will allow this, as equivalent to

```
char string[5] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

Note that there will *not* be a string null-terminator added.

See e.g. [this array initialization reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

Also note that this is one of the *many* places where C differs from C++, where this is not allowed.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if `g++`'s `-fpermissive` is intended for "Accept C code in a C++ context".

Comment: @Joshua: I'd rather assume it's to compile legacy C++ code. maybe pre-C++98 or whenever this has changed from the C-like behaviour. There are way to many differences to care about this one.